# Distribute Time over milliseconds for a smooth curve

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe in which one column contains datetime. The datetime is till seconds. I need to automatically add milliseconds to the seconds as I have multiple values for each second value. 
For example- Feb 21, 2019 3:50:41 PM, I have this time stamp for 35 times. If I can add milliseconds to this time stamp so when I will plot the curve it will be a smooth one. and every second value has a different number of instances.

Comment: Instead of adding milliseconds, would it be interesting to only care about the `mean` of all the values for each second?

Comment: @Ben.T I cant mean the value, I need value for every millisecond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `groupby` to modify the date

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(['Feb 21, 2019 3:50:41 PM']*35 + 
                                          ['Feb 21, 2019 3:50:42 PM']*100),
                        'val': np.linspace(0,1,135)})

def time_shift(s):
    count = len(s)
    deltas = pd.timedelta_range('0ms', '1000ms',
                                periods=count+1, closed='left')
    return s + deltas

df.date = df.groupby(['date']).date.transform(time_shift)

plt.plot(df.date, df.val)
```

Plot of original dataframe:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Plot after scaling by milliseconds:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Dataframe after shift:

```
df.tail(5)

+-----+-------------------------------+----------+
|     | date                          |      val |
|-----+-------------------------------+----------|
| 130 | 2019-02-21 15:50:42.959595959 | 0.970149 |
| 131 | 2019-02-21 15:50:42.969696969 | 0.977612 |
| 132 | 2019-02-21 15:50:42.979797979 | 0.985075 |
| 133 | 2019-02-21 15:50:42.989898989 | 0.992537 |
| 134 | 2019-02-21 15:50:43           | 1        |
+-----+-------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have one doubt actually the time series that I have is starting from Feb 21, 2019 3:50:39 PM TO Feb 21, 2019 3:52:35 PM. I have around 7000 rows. Now if by any means it can count the same time instances and distribute it over milliseconds. As 35 is not constant some time instant occurs for 40 times some for 65 times.

Comment: It's an example. The function `time_shift` will scale according to each block of seconds.

Comment: can you help me in using this function as I am printing df['Time'] I am getting this    '0       Feb 21, 2019 3:50:39 PM
1       Feb 21, 2019 3:50:39 PM
2       Feb 21, 2019 3:50:39 PM
3       Feb 21, 2019 3:50:39 PM
4       Feb 21, 2019 3:50:39 PM'

Comment: in my code the timestamp column is `date`. So try to change all the `.date` to `.Time` , and also make sure that `df['Time']` has type `datetime` (`df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']`).

Comment: Thanks, its working fine just one thing that when a new second come the its giving two same value with 00 milliseconds like -->                                         
2019-02-21 15:50:39.909090909
2019-02-21 15:50:40.000000000
2019-02-21 15:50:40.000000000
2019-02-21 15:50:40.016949152

Comment: It's working. Thank you so much for your help and patience.